# 32,7893256547 is not a valid BCD value

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I have a Numeric(26,10) column "x" in SQL Server 2008.  When I try to read the column values using TADOQuery's FieldByName('x').AsExtended, I get an error "32,7893256547 is not a valid BCD value".

"32,7893256547" is one of the column values.

This happens only on some computers.  On those computers, When I change the windows setting "No. of digits after decimal" to 9 in region settings, then everything works fine.

I see that column is mapped to TFMTBCDField in ADOQuery.

Is it a problem with BCD conversions / formatting ? And how can I solve this problem?

Platform:
Windows 7, Delphi 2009, SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Sounds like your issue is the decimal separator - `,` vs `.`.

Comment: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=2741

Comment: also, try this - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TCustomADODataSet.EnableBCD

Comment: @Eric : No. "," decimal seperator is not an issue.  I checked that. It has to do with number of digits after decimal.

Comment: @RBA : I cannot use EnableBCD because of its currency type. And I try the other suggestions.  Is there any way to reproduce the same issue on all computers?  On some systems, no matter what value I set for the regional setting "No. of digits after decimal", it is always working.

Comment: And if you try  FieldByName('x').AsCurrency?

Comment: @Arnaud : According to docs, Currency type has only 4 digits after decimal point, which is not useful in this case.

Comment: Do why not just use FieldByName('x').AsString then process the conversion on your side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I tried to use

```
ADOQuery1.FieldByName('YourField').AsString;
```

Solved with this:

```
BCDToStrf(ADOQuery1.FieldByName('YourField').AsBCD,ffFixed,11,3) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Me helps change in Windows 7 decimal point from comma to point and back in Start > Control panel > Clock, language and Region > Change date, time and numbers format and change decimal point for numbers and currency from to comma to point or the other way around and back.

Sorry, but I'm using Windows in Czech and we have comma separator as default decimal point. Some caption are translated to English by me so they needn't be exact.